# The SUM of column in Join table SQL PHP not working

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, union, aggregate-functions

I am trying to calculate and get the SUM of column `count` from table `table_two`. I am trying to fetch and get a sum of the column by the `Left Join` function. but it is not working correctly and the SUM of a column I am getting times of row to exist in `table_two`.

I am not perfect well in the union table with `left JOIN` could you please help me with how to use the union function in my code.
I show the multiple threads on this StackOverflow but believe me it was tough to understand and very big. that's why I am making here a small table for help and easily understandable.

Please help me don't mark it as duplicate and closed sir. I am trying for the past 1weeks but no code working.

I am trying the code is -

```
SELECT *, SUM(table_two.count) AS totalQTY, SUM(table_one.qty) AS totalReqQty 
    FROM table_one 
    LEFT JOIN table_two 
        ON table_one product_key = product_code 
    LEFT JOIN product_table 
        ON table_two.product_code = product_table.product_ids
```

`table_one`

```
|  ID  | product_key      |  insert_date |  qty 
|------|------------------|--------------|------
|  1   | 123456789        |  2021-02-01  |  150    
------------------------------------------------
```

`table_two`

```
|  ID  | product_code      |  add_date    |  count 
|------|-------------------|--------------|-------
|  1   | 123456789         |  2021-02-02  |   10
|  2   | 123456789         |  2021-02-03  |   20
|  3   | 123456789         |  2021-02-04  |   5
--------------------------------------------------
```

`product_table`

```
|  ID  | product_ids       |  product_name   
|------|-------------------|----------------------
|  1   | 123456789         |  XYZ
--------------------------------------------------
```

`Expecting Output:`

```
|  ID  | product_key       |  product_name  |  qty  | count |
|------|-------------------|---------------------------------
|  1   | 123456789         |  XYZ           |  150  |  35   | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [query you showed us](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xd4rax25LYQQFRfxGv7erN/0) does not work.

If you want to summarize / roll up / your data by using [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) like SUM() your best bet is to start by running the query without them. [For example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xd4rax25LYQQFRfxGv7erN/1)

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM table_one 
    LEFT JOIN table_two 
        ON table_one.product_key = table_two.product_code 
    LEFT JOIN product_table 
        ON table_two.product_code = product_table.product_ids
```

You get this result. Notice that it has three rows, and the qty `150` shows up in all three.

| ID | product_key | insert_date | qty | ID | product_code | add_date | count | ID | product_ids | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456789 | 2021-02-01 | 150 | 1 | 123456789 | 2021-02-02 | 10 | 1 | 123456789 | XYZ |
| 1 | 123456789 | 2021-02-01 | 150 | 2 | 123456789 | 2021-02-03 | 20 | 1 | 123456789 | XYZ |
| 1 | 123456789 | 2021-02-01 | 150 | 3 | 123456789 | 2021-02-04 | 5 | 1 | 123456789 | XYZ |

Then, keep in mind that when you sum up multiple rows, the detail in those rows (for example, `table_1.ID`) isn't meaningful any more. Which ID do you want when three rows are added up?

So you can do [something like this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xd4rax25LYQQFRfxGv7erN/2)

```sql
SELECT table_one.product_key, 
       SUM(table_two.count) totalQty,
       SUM(table_one.qty) totalReqQty
  FROM table_one 
  LEFT JOIN table_two 
           ON table_one.product_key = table_two.product_code 
  LEFT JOIN product_table 
           ON table_two.product_code = product_table.product_ids
 GROUP BY table_one.product_key
```

That gives this result, which is incorrect -- it triple-sums `table_one.qty`. Your JOIN of `table_one` and `table_two` caused a combinatorial explosion.

| product_key | totalQty | totalReqQty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 35 | 450 **WRONG!** |

So, what you need in is to understand that your top level `FROM table_one ... JOIN table_two ... JOIN product_table...` pattern needs to join together a single row in `table_one`, `table_two`, and `product_table` for each product.  In this setup you're fine for  `product_table`. It has one row for each product.

But the other tables can have multiple rows per product. So you need to SUM them in subqueries, and join the subqueries, [like this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xd4rax25LYQQFRfxGv7erN/3).

```sql
SELECT product_table.product_ids,
       table_two_summary.totalQty,
       table_one_summary.totalReqQty
  FROM product_table
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT product_code, SUM(count) totalQty
              FROM table_two
             GROUP BY product_code
       ) table_two_summary 
         ON product_table.product_ids = table_two_summary.product_code
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT product_key, SUM(qty) totalReqQty
              FROM table_one
             GROUP BY product_key
       ) table_one_summary 
         ON product_table.product_ids = table_one_summary.product_key
```

**Edit** if you need to filter on the summed-up columns you can do it [like this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xd4rax25LYQQFRfxGv7erN/4).

```sql
SELECT product_table.product_ids,
       table_two_summary.totalQty,
       table_one_summary.totalReqQty
  FROM product_table
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT product_code, SUM(count) totalQty
              FROM table_two
             GROUP BY product_code
       ) table_two_summary 
         ON product_table.product_ids = table_two_summary.product_code
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT product_key, SUM(qty) totalReqQty
              FROM table_one
             GROUP BY product_key
       ) table_one_summary 
         ON product_table.product_ids = table_one_summary.product_key
 WHERE table_one_summary.totalReqQty > table_two_summary.totalQty
```

See how the subqueries summarize the two different tables separately. If you join them and summarize them you'll count some rows multiple times.

Comment: You make my day, but when I use `where` condition  with this code `sum(table_one.qty) > sum(table_two.count)` the it is not workig

Comment: Please see my edit. And, with respect, "not working" is not a meaningful statement. It could mean anything from "giving incorrect results" to "throwing a syntax error" to "making my server catch fire and burn down my data center." You'll gain skill if you examine code errors and try to give more meaningful explanations.

Comment: but it is not working `table_one_summary.product_key` not save

Comment: please fix this issue

Comment: but your code showing null value `https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xd4rax25LYQQFRfxGv7erN/5` see your db_fiddle and help us to improve this

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged the database you are using, however one way to obtain the aggregations from each would be using `apply`.

I would also suggest you amend the inconsistencies in the naming convention of your ProductId, you are referring to it as `product_code` and `product_key` and `product_ids`. Deciding what to call it and being *consistent* will make it much easier for others to understand.

```
select p.product_ids as product_key, p.product_name, coalesce(q.Qty,0) totalQty, coalesce(c.[count],0) [Count]
from product_table p
outer apply (
    select sum(qty) Qty
    from table_one t1
    where t1.product_key=p.product_ids
    group by t1.product_key
)q
outer apply (
    select Sum(count) [count]
    from table_two t2
    where t2.product_code=p.product_ids
    group by t2.product_code
)c
```

Comment: `[` unexpectable character error

Comment: The OQ uses MySQL. This `[]` stuff is SQL Server.